# Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle Flutter

Tags: flutter

Logs:

```
distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
You can try some of the following options:
  - changing the IDE settings.
  - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
  - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

I tried:

- reinstalled the .gradle file
- I am using java 1.8

Comment: can you check `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: Question titles should be a summary of the problem, not general begging.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix this error,

Change your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
 distributionUrl https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip.
```

And `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
    }
```

For all of project be clean following these steps,

- Open the Project Structure in File (Android Studio)
- Click on the Gradle Settings link
- Select the correct Java JDK from the Gradle JDK drop-down list (picture)
  [image]

If you cannot find the Java JDK, then you'll first need to install it.